# Qt for x32 Windows computers

Tags: qt

I was trying to install Qt framework in a x32 computer but the installation was unsuccessful. Is there a Qt installer meant for x32 computers?

Comment: installing failed with what message? maybe the issue is not related to the arch but to another factors in the computer....

Comment: MSVC.dll error. I tried downloading the .dll file and put it in the installation folder but still null and void